# Using ToLookup with two fields

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I am new to linq to object and this looks simple to me. I have multiple customernumber
and day repeated in a collection. I want to order by day and customer number and show distinct
day and customer number.

How do I add the customerNbr to the .ToLookup ?

```
var queryResult = getRouteInfoPdfPurpose.OrderBy(t => t.Day).ThenBy(n => n.CustomerNbr)
                           .ToLookup(t => t.Day);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var queryResult = getRouteInfoPdfPurpose.OrderBy(t => t.Day).ThenBy(n => n.CustomerNbr).ToLookup(t => new {t.Day, t.CustomerNbr });
```